# Show that $Y$ is not path-connected

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness, path-connected

Let $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology and let

$$ Y = A_0 \cup (\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n) \cup (\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}L_n)$$

where

$$ A_0 = \{ 0 \} \times [0,1] \qquad A_n =  \{ {\dfrac{1}{n}} \} \times [0,1]  \qquad \textrm{and $L_n$ is the segment between $(\dfrac{1}{n},1)$ and $(\dfrac{1}{n+1},0)$}$$

I need to show that $Y$ is not path-connected.

My intuition is that there cannot be any continuous function $f:[0,1] \to Y$ such that (for example) $f(0) = (0,0)$ and $f(1) = (1,1)$ because it is not going to be continuous at $(0,0)$, but I cannot prove that formally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is good. To make it precise, let $\pi_1,\pi_2$ denote the coordinate projections $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Then suppose there were a continuous $f\colon [0,1]\to Y$ with $f(0) = (0,0)$ and $f(1) = (1,1)$. Let $g = \pi_1\circ f$, and define

$$t_n = \inf \left\{ t \in [0,1] : g(t) = \frac{1}{n}\right\}.$$

Looking at $(f(t_n))$ leads to a contradiction.

Comment: why does looking at $(f(t_n))$ lead to a contradiction?

Comment: a) what is $f(t_n)$? b) what property has the sequence $(t_n)$? Note: you can't conclude $t_n \to 0$, but what you can conclude is sufficiently similar.

Comment: Oh, it is clear now.Thanks! =D

Comment: @Daniel I can see that $f(t_n) = (1/n,1)$ (I hope) but I don't see how we can state that $f(t)$ is not continuous unless we can conclude that $t_n \to 0$.

Comment: @user157227 Yes, $f(t_n) = (1/n,1)$. Further, $(t_n)$ is monotonically decreasing. Then you know that it converges to $s \geqslant 0$. And you know that $f(s) = (0,x)$ for some $x$. If $x < 1$, case closed. If $x = 1$ (and so far we can't exclude that), we need a further step indeed to conclude that $f$ is not continuous: Let $u_n = \sup \{t\in [t_n,t_{n-1}) : g(t) = 1/n\}$. Then $f(u_n) = (1/n,0)$, and $u_n\to s$ (since $t_n < u_n < t_{n-1}$) gives the contradiction.